# Real Time Clock PCF8523 & ESP32-C6: Registers don’t match data sheet?

Tags: i2c, esp32, rtc, esp-idf

I'm trying to use a PCF8523 RTC (via adafruit's assembled breakout board) with an ESP32-C6 (via ESP32-C6-DevKitC-1) over I2C.

**It appears the bits inside each register shift around unexpectedly?** According to the data sheet, I should be able to get the control information from 00h to 02h. These should be relatively static, except for oscillator startup? There's also a brand new CR1220 battery acting as the backup power source.

The datasheet (and related materials) can be accessed at the following links:

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCF8523.pdf

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/PCF8523-1127521.pdf

6.2.2 Reading the clock - https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10760.pdf

For the relevant datasheet section, see below:
[image: PCF8523 Datasheet showing registers overview]

**The 02h register appears to increment every minute, which would suggest I'm not reading the Control_3 register.**

I've also tried reading starting from the 03h register up to and including the 09h register. It appears that it flips the order of registers. Minutes end up last (even though they should be in 2nd place), seconds in 2nd last place, and what I guess appear to be milliseconds in 3rd last?

The chip has 8523T written on it, and I purchased it from DigiKey, which resells Adafruit's PCB.

This is the output I receive when I'm using the monitor from inside the code editor:

```
ESP-ROM:esp32c6-20220919
Build:Sep 19 2022
entry 0x4086c410
I (23) boot: ESP-IDF v5.1 2nd stage bootloader
I (23) boot: compile time Jul  9 2023 20:14:48
I (369) cpu_start: cpu freq: 160000000 Hz
I (369) cpu_start: Application information:
I (372) cpu_start: Project name:     project-name
I (377) cpu_start: App version:      1
I (382) cpu_start: Compile time:     Jul  9 2023 20:13:59
I (388) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  5964684f2d6759f4...
I (394) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v5.1
I (399) cpu_start: Min chip rev:     v0.0
I (403) cpu_start: Max chip rev:     v0.99 
I (408) cpu_start: Chip rev:         v0.0
I (472) app_start: Starting scheduler on CPU0
I (477) main_task: Started on CPU0
I (477) main_task: Calling app_main()
Hello world!
Detected Host Little Endian.
I (1517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 684
ctrl0: 11101101 | ctrl1: 00000101 | ctrl2: 00000000 | 
I (5517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 688
ctrl0: 10001101 | ctrl1: 00010101 | ctrl2: 00000000 |
I (8517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 691
ctrl0: 01000101 | ctrl1: 00100001 | ctrl2: 00000000 |
I (11517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 694
ctrl0: 11111101 | ctrl1: 00101100 | ctrl2: 00000000 |
I (14517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 697
ctrl0: 10110101 | ctrl1: 00111000 | ctrl2: 00000000 |
I (17517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 700
ctrl0: 01101101 | ctrl1: 01000100 | ctrl2: 00000000 |
...
I (62517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 745
ctrl0: 00110101 | ctrl1: 11110100 | ctrl2: 00000000 |
I (65517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 748
ctrl0: 11101101 | ctrl1: 11111111 | ctrl2: 00000000 |
I (68517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 751
ctrl0: 10100101 | ctrl1: 00001011 | ctrl2: 00000001 |
I (71517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 754
ctrl0: 01011101 | ctrl1: 00010111 | ctrl2: 00000001 |
I (74517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 757
ctrl0: 00010101 | ctrl1: 00100011 | ctrl2: 00000001 |
I (77517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 760
ctrl0: 11001101 | ctrl1: 00101110 | ctrl2: 00000001 |
I (80517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 763
ctrl0: 10000101 | ctrl1: 00111010 | ctrl2: 00000001 |
...
I (125517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 808
ctrl0: 01001101 | ctrl1: 11101010 | ctrl2: 00000001 |
I (128517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 811
ctrl0: 00000101 | ctrl1: 11110110 | ctrl2: 00000001 |
I (131517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 814
ctrl0: 10111101 | ctrl1: 00000001 | ctrl2: 00000010 |
I (134517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 817
ctrl0: 01110101 | ctrl1: 00001101 | ctrl2: 00000010 |
I (137517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 820
ctrl0: 00101101 | ctrl1: 00011001 | ctrl2: 00000010 |
I (140517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 823
ctrl0: 11100101 | ctrl1: 00100100 | ctrl2: 00000010 |
I (143517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 826
ctrl0: 10011101 | ctrl1: 00110000 | ctrl2: 00000010 |
...
I (677517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 1360
ctrl0: 10001101 | ctrl1: 01010110 | ctrl2: 00001010 |
I (680517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 1363
ctrl0: 01000101 | ctrl1: 01100010 | ctrl2: 00001010 |
I (683517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 1366
ctrl0: 11111101 | ctrl1: 01101101 | ctrl2: 00001010 |
I (686517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 1369
ctrl0: 10110101 | ctrl1: 01111001 | ctrl2: 00001010 |
I (689517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 1372
ctrl0: 01101101 | ctrl1: 10000101 | ctrl2: 00001010 |
I (692517) RTC: Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: 1375
```

I've based my ESP-IDF C code on the following links:

https://gist.github.com/menesesleonardo/2fa6d702ac2d8031b463c21439cf40de

https://github.com/SMFSW/arm_i2c_drivers/blob/master/PCF8523.h

https://github.com/UncleRus/esp-idf-lib/blob/master/components/pcf8563/pcf8563.c

My code is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "driver/i2c.h"
#include <inttypes.h>

static char tag[] = "RTC";

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format
#define BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c"
#define BYTE_TO_BINARY(byte)  \
  ((byte) & 0x80 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x40 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x20 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x10 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x08 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x04 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x02 ? '1' : '0'), \
  ((byte) & 0x01 ? '1' : '0') 

#define I2C_MASTER_NUM        0      /*!< I2C master i2c port number, the number of i2c peripheral interfaces available will depend on the chip */
#define I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO     0      /*!<gpio number for i2c master clock  */
#define I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO     2      /*!<gpio number for i2c master data */
#define I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ    100000 /*!< I2C master clock frequency */
#define I2C_MASTER_TIMEOUT_MS 1000
#define I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE   0  /*!< I2C master doesn't need buffer */
#define I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE   0  /*!< I2C master doesn't need buffer */

void rtc_readControl3() {
    i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_start(cmd));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (rtc_pcf8523_address << 1) | I2C_MASTER_WRITE, true /* expect ack */));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, 0x00, 1)); // start address
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_start(cmd));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (rtc_pcf8523_address << 1) | I2C_MASTER_READ, true /* expect ack */));
    uint8_t data[3];
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_read(cmd, data, 3, false));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(i2c_master_stop(cmd));
    i2c_master_cmd_begin(I2C_NUM_0, cmd, 1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("ctrl%d: "BYTE_TO_BINARY_PATTERN" | ", i, BYTE_TO_BINARY(data[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void app_main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    // https://hackaday.com/2020/08/04/dont-let-endianness-flip-you-around/
    uint16_t bytes = 1;
    if (*((uint8_t*) &bytes) == 1) {
        printf("Detected Host Little Endian.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Detected Host Big Endian.\n");
    }
    
    // i2c bus configuration:
    i2c_config_t conf = {
        .mode = I2C_MODE_MASTER,
        .sda_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SDA_IO,         // select SDA GPIO specific to your project, 2 is the default?
        .sda_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .scl_io_num = I2C_MASTER_SCL_IO,         // select SCL GPIO specific to your project, 0 is the default?
        .scl_pullup_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
        .master.clk_speed = I2C_MASTER_FREQ_HZ,  // select frequency specific to your project
        .clk_flags = 0,                          // optional; you can use I2C_SCLK_SRC_FLAG_* flags to choose i2c source clock here
    };
    
    while (1) {
        // Commonly called "i2c_master_init()":
        i2c_param_config(I2C_MASTER_NUM, &conf); // Set the master port and load the configuration from a given address.
        i2c_driver_install(I2C_MASTER_NUM, conf.mode, I2C_MASTER_RX_BUF_DISABLE, I2C_MASTER_TX_BUF_DISABLE, 0);
        
        time_t seconds2; // Represented by a long long int (64 bit time!)
        seconds2 = time(NULL);
        //printf("Seconds since January 1, 1970 = %lld\n", seconds2);
        ESP_LOGI(tag,"Current time in processor rtc (raw) is: %lld", seconds2);
        
        rtc_readControl3();

        i2c_driver_delete(I2C_MASTER_NUM); // Remove the driver from the given 'master port'.

        vTaskDelay(3000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
    
    vTaskDelay(5000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    fflush(stdout);
    esp_restart();
}
```

**Any ideas on what might be going on, or how to fix this?** I would be prototyping with the Arduino IDE but it doesn't (at time of writing) support ESP-IDF V5.1, which is required for the ESP32-C6...

Things I've tried, but didn't fix the issue:

- Resetting the ESP32.
- Removing the 5V power source, removing the battery, waiting about 20 seconds.
- Changing what register(s) I'm reading from, and how many.
- Letting it run for >2 minutes.
- Flashing and then re-flashing the code after a successful compilation.
- Using a full clean build, rebuilding the bootloader and such.
- Writing out the "raw" binary representation of the values.
- Using binary decimal notation to get the time values (other code).
- Checking that I'm actually using a PCF8523.

My best guesses:

- The endianness of either the ESP32-C6 or I2C is giving some odd results.
- Pins 0 and 2 can't be used for SCL, SDA? Pinout for the ESP32-c6 dev board suggests this is ok?
- There's an obvious error in my code that I can't see?

**EDIT:** This is the result of printing out all 20 registers, in order from 0 (00h) to 19 (13h). You can clearly see they don't line up with the data sheet:

```
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11100011    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10010   110 0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11100111    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11000110    10101   0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11101010    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10010010    100001  0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11101101    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1011110 101101  0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11110000    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   101010  111001  0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11110011    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11110110    1000100 0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11110110    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11000010    1010000 0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11111001    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10001110    1011100 0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11111100    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1011010 1101000 0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11111111    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100110  1110100 0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11110010    1111111 0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 101 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10111110    10001011    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1000    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10001010    10010111    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1011    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1010110 10100011    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1110    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100010  10101111    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10001   11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11101110    10111010    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10100   11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10111010    11000110    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10111   11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10000110    11010010    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11010   11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1010010 11011110    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11101   11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11110   11101010    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 100000  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11101010    11110101    0   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 100011  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10110110    1   1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 100110  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10000010    1101    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 101001  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1001110 11001   1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 101100  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11010   100101  1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 101111  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11100110    110000  1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 110010  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10110010    111100  1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 110101  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1111110 1001000 1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 111000  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1001010 1010100 1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 111011  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10110   1100000 1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 111111  11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11100010    1101011 1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1000010 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10101110    1110111 1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1000101 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1111010 10000011    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1001000 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1000110 10001111    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1001011 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10010   10011011    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1001110 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11011110    10100110    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1010001 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10101010    10110010    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1010100 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1110110 10111110    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1010111 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1000010 11001010    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1011010 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1110    11010110    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1011101 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11011010    11100001    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1100000 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10100110    11101101    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1100011 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1110010 11111001    1   0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1100110 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   111110  101 10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1101001 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1010    10001   10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1101100 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11010110    11100   10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1101111 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10100010    101000  10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1110010 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1101110 110100  10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1110101 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   111010  1000000 10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1111000 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   110 1001100 10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1111011 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11010010    1010111 10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 1111110 11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10011110    1100011 10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10000001    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1101010 1101111 10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10000100    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   110110  1111011 10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10000111    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  10000111    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10001010    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11001110    10010010    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10001101    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10011010    10011110    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10010000    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1100110 10101010    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10010011    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   110010  10110110    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10010110    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11111110    11000001    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10011001    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11001010    11001101    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10011100    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10010110    11011001    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10011111    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1100010 11100101    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10100010    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   101110  11110001    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10100101    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11111010    11111100    10  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10101000    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11000110    1000    11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10101011    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10010010    10100   11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10101110    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1011110 100000  11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10110001    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   101010  101100  11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10110100    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11110110    110111  11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10110111    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11000010    1000011 11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10111010    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10001110    1001111 11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 10111101    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1011010 1011011 11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11000000    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100110  1100111 11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11000011    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11110010    1110010 11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11000110    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10111110    1111110 11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11001001    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   10001010    10001010    11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11001100    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1010110 10010110    11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11001111    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   100010  10100010    11  0
1100100 1101000 0   1000010 11010010    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   11101110    10101101    11  0
```